High SE in Binomial distribution
probably a dumb question, but im working on housefly mortality related to different tratments and im trying to run a ANOVA with binomial distribution comparing these treatments.
The thing is that i have a treatment which kills all the flies in my repetitions (all my data is 1), when i run the analysis it shows a high standard error (and groups my treatment with all the rest).
I would think that there is something I am doing wrong since my logic tells me that, having no variation throughout the repetitions, the standard error should be low (likewise, I performed an ANOVA transforming the data, in which the SE of that treatment is low).
Here is my script:
library(lme4)
y <- cbind(binomial$muertas, binomial$vivas)
m1 <- glm(y ~ cepa, data = binomial, family = binomial(link = logit))
summary(m1)

My console shows the following (I removed the treatments that don't matter):
Coefficients:
             Estimate  Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
  
(Intercept)  0.4520     0.2162    2.090   0.0366 

cepa1740     18.6846   914.5296   0.020   0.9837

  

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Pease let me know if you need something more, i don't know too much about statistics

This is an example of perfect separation. See this page and its many links for ways to deal with this. If those links don't answer your question, please edit your question to specify what you still don't understand. The problem is that the assumptions needed to get reliable standard errors used for Wald tests of individual coefficient estimates don't hold when all cases having some combination of predictors have the same outcome. Your likelihood-ratio test should still be fine.
